# php "if" condition mystery

Tags: php, if-statement

I am running into a funny problem with a mischievous "if" condition :

```
$condition1="53==56";
$condition2="53==57";
$condition3="53==58";
$condition=$condition1."||".$condition2."||".$condition3;
if($condition)
{
    echo "blah";
}
else
{
    echo "foo";
}
```

Why does the if condition pass? 
Why does php echo "blah"? What do I do to make php evaluate the "if" statement and print "foo"?

Comment: sorry, but why shouldn't that condition pass? :P

Comment: @sniper I'm simply curious. I've never seen anyone trying to do it this way, so I'm wondering where you got the syntax from.

Comment: @sniper - I think @ceejayoz might be wondering if you found this code from some sort of example or tutorial, and I think that's a perfectly valid question. There are quite a few _highly questionable_ PHP 'learning resources' out there ;)

Comment: Regarding this question, it is clear and perfectly on topic. If you don't know, you have to ask someone, and that's what the author is doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that you're putting your expressions in strings!

Your `$condition1`, `$condition2`, and `$condition3` variables contain strings, and not the result of an expression, and the same goes for your `$condition` variable which will be a string that looks like `53==56||53==57||53==58`. When PHP evaluates a string it considers it `true` if it is not empty and not equal to `0`, so your script will output `blah`.

To fix this you just need to take your expressions out of the strings. It should look like this:

```
$condition1 = 53 == 56; // false
$condition2 = 53 == 57; // false
$condition3 = 53 == 58; // false
$condition = $condition1 || $condition2 || $condition3; // false || false || false = false

if ($condition) {
    echo 'blah';
} else {
    echo 'foo'; // This will be output
}
```

Comment: When you use double quotes PHP attempts to parse the contents of that string. For example if you have the string "Hello $name!" in double quotes then PHP will look through the string for variable names and replace them with the variable's value if it exists. This is all well and good, but it wastes time (a minimal amount, but it all adds up). Strings in single quotes aren't parsed. I use single quotes wherever I can. Also it means you can echo HTML like so `echo '<div id="header">';` without having to escape the double quotes. :)

Comment: Double quotes waste time, and it all adds up? - You've never actually looked at a profiler graph, did you?

Comment: Single quotes also parse looking for escaped single quotes.  No time gained.

Comment: I did some benchmark testing on single/double quotes. I printed 1,000,000 pages of identical content "This is a test. " copied and pasted for 1 page. After 10 hours, the evidence surprised me. Double quotes proved to be the faster method when no parsing was required, completing in 20215.063497066 seconds, where as single quotes took 21377.586787939 seconds to complete.

Answer (score 7):

You're evaluating strings as booleans; they'll aways be true (except the strings `""` and `"0"`. Get rid of almost all of the quotes in your program.

Comment: Thanks wooble. Get rid of which quotes?

Comment: Every `"` except around `"blah"` and `"foo"`, which are the only actual strings. (ceejayoz has provided the corrected code...)

Answer (score 5):

Those aren't conditions, they're strings.

```
$condition1=53==56;
$condition2=53==57;
$condition3=53==58;
$condition=$condition1 || $condition2 || $condition3;
if($condition)
{
    echo "blah";
}
else
{
    echo "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you're not checking those variables, it's saying `if (String)` will always return true. (unless `""`)

You should be doing:

```
if(53==56 || 53==57 || 53==58)
{
    echo "blah";
}
else
{
    echo "foo";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All `$condition*` variables will evaluate to true. This is how PHP sees it:

```
if("53==56" || "53==57" || "53==58")
```

What you want is this:

```
$condition1 = 53==56;
$condition2 = 53==57;
$condition3 = 53==58;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're evaluating a string, and strings other than empty strings evaluate to true.

Answer (score 2):

You are concatting a string together, a non-empty string equals `TRUE` in php.

Answer (score 1):

Because when the if passes, $condition is a string (a concatenation of) containing the text of your conditions. Try using `if(eval($condition))`.

Comment: `eval` should be avoided if at all possible. It's dangerous.

Comment: It is, but you can't say it's not what he's trying to do.

Comment: +1 because it is interesting information (how to evaluate an expression stored in a string).  Though it isn't obvious from context whether this is really what the OP is trying to do, or not.  They may be new and not understand the difference between different data types, expression evaluation inside `if` blocks, why you'd quote something, etc.

Comment: `eval` does not work with expressions. You need to execute a statement like `if (eval("return $condition;"))` for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

String always evaluate to true if its not empty
And btw php make implicit conversion to boolean